# How do I save the content after the onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I already connected the html with js and I get the data from a form when the onclick is activated but since I save each data that I receive to use it later, how do I get the data out of the function without having problems:

```js
var getData = () => {
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let age = document.getElementById("age").value;

  if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
  } else {
    if (age == "") {
      document.getElementById("age").focus();
    } else {
      console.log(name + " " + age);
      document.getElementById("name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("age").value = "";
      document.getElementById("name").focus();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: "since I save each data that I receive to use it later" — Save it where?

Comment: "how do I get the data out of the function" — out of the function … to where?

Comment: "without having problems" — What problems are you having?

Comment: Or, to summarize, please remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73072232/edit) accordingly. Folks have no idea what you're doing, so explain your situation, what you wanted to do, what you decided to implement to do that, what it did, how that didn't match what you expected, _and_ what you already tried to fix it.

Comment: Excuse me if I don't make myself understood, it's just that I'm new to this platform.
I just want to save the form data in a simple variable, I have the data in the getData function and I don't know how to put it in variables

var data = "THE NAME THAT THE USER ENTERED";
something like that, sorry.

Comment: @ElianF — Why do you need it in a variable? Why not read it from the inputs when you need it? And if you do need it in a variable, what problem are you having assign it to one? There's no attempt to do that in the code you've provided.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an external variable to save the data you want, when the function you are using finishes, the data in it "disapears". So, in order to save it, you should create an external variable.

Anyways, should be good to know a bit more of the problem that you are facing with.